# extending from extenal html file

Tags: django, django-urls

extend base.html from /blog/templates/base.html into users app in users/templates/users/register.html:

I can't extend 'blog/template/base.html' in users app.

I use this code:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
```

Here is my project image:

[image]

Error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /register/
>
> Blockquote
>
> Blockquote
>
> blog/base.html
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/register/
>   Django Version:   2.2 Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist Exception
>   Value:
>
> blog/base.html

Comment: it is `extends` not `extend`

Comment: yes. i correct that. but still not working

Comment: try it,.. {% extends ‘blog/templates/base.html’ %}

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of apps in INSTALLED_APPS is important for use templates.

From Django official docs on [order of INSTALLED_APPS in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#installed-apps) :

> When several applications provide different versions of the same
>   resource (template, static file, management command, translation), the
>   application listed first in `INSTALLED_APPS` has precedence.

Thus your project must use first template folder.

You can move 'base.html' file to parent template folder, Or change INSTALLED_APPS orders.

Comment: yse. it worked. thanks. :) this was my problem: 

The order of apps in INSTALLED_APPS is important for use templates